# Data source authentication with DBCP connection Pooling

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, ldap, jndi

Presently I am using Hibernate for the DB credentials. I am using the JNDI which is mentioned in the Tomcat Server's `contxt.xml` file. It is using the Commons DBCP Connection pooling.

In the `Hibernate.cfg.xml` file we are mentioning the data source details only.

Now my requirement is to use the LDAP authentication for the DB details since we are providing the DB credentials directly in the `context.xml` file.

I have to use LDAP authentication for connection pooling by hiding the DB Credentials in the server.

Please Adivice how can i implement that in my context.xml?

Comment: Please Adivice how can i implement that in my context.xml?

Comment: Sorry Guys, I have solved the issue, we need to provide the data source driver url some thing like this jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ldap.server.name:4042/schemaname,cn=OracleContext,dc=fm,dc=rbsgrp,dc=net  u can ge the LDAP url in your Oracle installation directory it will be something like C:\oracle\Ora920\network\ADMIN\ldap.ora file and datasource will be in your tomcat server either in server.xml file or context.xml file